# Issues generating array in object for Json

Tags: c#, json

I am trying to fill the following object with the the data from a list object.

```
public class DocumentQueryObject
{
    public Document[] documents { get; set; }
}

public class Document
{
    public DocumentObj document { get; set; }
}
public class DocumentObj
{
    public string homecommunityid { get; set; }
    public string repositoryid { get; set; }
    public string documentuuid { get; set; }
    public string doctype { get; set; }
}
```

I need this to be able to build the following JSON

```
{
"documents": {
    "document": [
        {
            "doctype": "",
            "homecommunityid": "2.16.470.1.100.1.1.1000.990.1",
            "repositoryid": "2.16.470.1.100.1.1.1000.990.1",
            "documentuuid": "91092"
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

So I am using the following c# code

```
DocumentQueryObject documents = new DocumentQueryObject()
                    {
                       documents = new[] {
                       new Document()
                          {
                             document = new []
                                {
                                   obj.Select(s => new DocumentObj()
                                      {
                                         doctype = s.doctype
                                      })
                                }
                            }
                       }
                    };
```

The obj is list of DocumentQuery objects below

```
public class DocumentQuery
{
        public string doctype { get; set; }
        public string homecommunityid { get; set; }
        public string repositoryid { get; set; }
        public string documentuuid { get; set; } 
}
```

So I need to assign these multiple DocumentQuery objects from the list to the DocumentQueryObject.

Can someone help?

Comment: Please show where the error is generated

Comment: Why are you creating two arrays in a nested structure?

Comment: Try posting your JSON to http://json2csharp.com/, you will see the error in your data model.  `DocumentQueryObject` should have a property `public Document documents` while `Document` should have a list property `public List<DocumentObj> document`.

Comment: Please include a screenshot of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Document` class has a property for **a** `DocumentObj` but you are trying to create an **array** of `DocumentObj`

You should be doing something like this:

```
DocumentQueryObject documents = new DocumentQueryObject()
{
    documents = new[] 
    {
        new Document()
        {
            document = new DocumentObj()
        }
    }   
};
```

Though you have not posted what `obj` is and what you are trying to achieve. Though the above may get rid of your error you may need to add more context to your problem for a more thorough answer.

#### Update

If you want document to be a collection then you can change your classes as suggested by @dbc in the comments:

```
public class Document
{
    public List<DocumentObj> document { get; set; }
}


DocumentQueryObject documents = new DocumentQueryObject()
{
    documents = new[] 
    {
        new Document()
        {
            document =
                obj.Select(s => new DocumentObj()
                {
                    doctype = s.doctype

                }).ToList()
        }
    }

};
```

Comment: This is kind of helpful but I need to fill with multiple DocumentObj() from obj. Obj is list of document properties. I am doing this:

Comment: `DocumentQueryObject documents = new DocumentQueryObject()
                        {
                            documents = new[]
                               {
                                new Document()
                                {
                                    document = obj.Select( a => new DocumentObj() {doctype = a.doctype })
                                    
                                    
                                }
                            }
                        };`